# автокомплит php переменных в VIsual Studio Code не печатая $ в начале

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, phpstorm, autocomplete

Как сделать автокомплит переменной не печатая знак **$**?

Например есть переменная $var_name.

В **phpstorm**, можно начать вводить var, нажать tab и переменная $var_name автоматически подставится вместе с $ вначале.

В **VSCode** нужно обязательно начинать вводить символ $ иначе переменная не появится в окошке.

Это можно как-то исправить?